# Is deserializing json to POJO really necessary in Android?

Tags: android, json, serialization, deserialization, pojo

I have a problem with understanding if it is necessary to deserialize a json array containing json objects into POJO's.

My problem isnt so much with HOW to do this but rather WHY?  And if there is a reason, how do I retrieve and manage these java objects when i need to use them?

For example, i have a user that search for vehicle Type A. The server returns the following json array:

```
[ {
   type: "A",
   colour: "blue",
   top_speed:"100km/h"
  },

  {
   type: "A",
   colour: "red",
   top_speed:"200km/h"
  },

  {
   type: "A",
   colour: "green",
   top_speed:"150km/h"
  }
]
```

So what I cant figure out is - is it really necessary to deserialize these json objects into java objects or is it acceptable to use the json array as it is and simply pass it directly as the datasource for my adapter? What I am currently doing is the following (and it works fine, for now at least):

```
JSONArray searchResults;

SearchResultsAdapter itemsAdapter = new SearchResultsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_search_result, searchResults);

 //next is a summary of my adapter:

public class SearchResultsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  JSONArray items;
  Context context;

  public SearchResultsAdapter(Context context, int resource, JSONArray objects) {
      super();

      this.items = objects;
      this.context = context;

  }

  @Override
  public JSONObject getItem(int i) {
      JSONObject item = null;
      try {
          item = (JSONObject) items.get(i);

      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return item;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

      LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

      if (view == null) {
          view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_search_result, viewGroup, false);
      }

      JSONObject item = (JSONObject) getItem(i);

      TextView typeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type);
      TextView colourView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.colour);
      TextView speedView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.speed);

      typeView.setText(item.optString("type"));
      typeView.setText(item.optString("colour"));
      typeView.setText(item.optString("top_speed"));
   }
}
```

Would this approach be acceptable? Does creating POJO's have any advantage over using this approach or am I being a total gunslinger cowboy coder here?

Comment: of course you dont need POJO, where did you find you need them?

Comment: **"Does creating POJO's have any advantage..."** There isn't really a right or wrong answer here. If all you want to do is as you've shown in your code then it is perfectly acceptable. If, however, you need to use the JSON data elsewhere then having it in some other form may be better, e.g., for persistence using a SQLite DB but even then it doesn't require the use of POJO's (quite the opposite in fact).